# Can't run ASP.NET Core project referencing full .NET Framework in 64-bit mode

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core project referencing .NET framework in 64-bit mode, but it seems to be running in 32-bit mode.

What I've tried is creating two simple default ASP.NET Core 2.0 projects. One referencing .NET Framework, and one referencing .NET Core. Like this:

**Project 1:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.4" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Project 2:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then, in `Startup.cs` i use the following code to check if I'm in 32- or 64-bit mode:

```
var size = IntPtr.Size;
```

For Project 1 `size` is `4`. For Project 2 `size` is `8`.

Isn't it possible to run .NET Framework applications in 64-bit mode?

I'm on 64-bit Windows 10, debugging the project in Visual Studio 15.7.3 (with IIS Express 10)

**Edit:**

The projects are configured to run using `AnyCPU`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Hadn't thought of that, but that actually seems to be the case. Tried changing to x64 instead of Any CPU and it runs in 64-bit mode now

Comment: FWIW, 64-bit is only necessary if you need to address more than 4GB of RAM per process, which is fairly unusual for a web application. If you think 64-bit is somehow better or more efficient than 32-bit, that's incorrect. If anything 64-bit is less efficient than 32-bit, since everything requires larger pointers.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Oh ok. I was under the impression that 32-bit has a limit of 2GB RAM per application pool, but maybe that isn't true on a 64 bit OS? Anyway, we have a web application processing quite large pieces of information in memory and we can see that IIS stops processing incoming requests when we reach ~1.5GB RAM. So we thought we'd give this a try. Could that be due to other factors you think?

Comment: 32-bit can address ~4 trillion pointers (2^32), so 4GB roughly. IIS itself needs some headroom so it's potentially lower practically. I'm not sure of the exact numbers there. However, a 1+ GB web process is kind of out there, anyways. It's very likely you've got a memory leak or some other inefficiency, which yes, could very well be responsible. Switching to 64-bit may actually just be hiding a larger issue.